# view key value rows as multi column single row

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

You have parameters x,y,z stored as key values.

[image]

You want to execute an expression z=x+y on those parameters. Expression is stored in another table.

You want to generate an SQL query as simply as possible from the expression.

How can you view those parameter values as a single row with columns (x,y,z) to enable execution of the expression ?

```
SELECT *
 INTO #key_values
FROM
(
SELECT 'x' AS mykey, 2 AS myvalue
UNION ALL
SELECT 'y',          5
UNION ALL
SELECT 'z',          0
) a;
```

Comment: "Expression is provided in the form of input data."  What does this mean?

Comment: changed to "Expression is stored in another table". I want to generate a query from the expression. It is actually going to be dynamic SQL with a query string generated with the expression as input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This screams for a `PIVOT` operator:

```
;WITH Inputs AS
(
    SELECT 'x' AS mykey, 2 AS myvalue
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'y',          5
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'z',          0
)
SELECT
    U.x,
    U.y,
    U.z,
    Result = U.x + U.y
FROM
    Inputs AS I
    PIVOT (
        MAX(I.myvalue) FOR I.mykey IN (x, y, z)
    ) AS U
```

Results:

```
x   y   z   Result
2   5   0   7
```

You can build any expression you want with the pivoted columns in the `SELECT`.

---

If you want to update the `z` record, you will have to join back to the underlying table since after applying the `PIVOT` you lose access to original table.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Input') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Input

CREATE TABLE #Input (
    mykey VARCHAR(10),
    myvalue INT)

INSERT INTO #Input (
    mykey,
    myvalue)
VALUES
    ('x', 2),
    ('y', 5),
    ('z', 0)

UPDATE I SET
    myvalue = R.Result
FROM
    #Input AS I
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT
            Result = x + y
        FROM
            #Input AS I
            PIVOT (MAX(I.myvalue) FOR I.mykey IN (x, y, z)) AS U
        ) AS R
WHERE
    I.mykey = 'z'
```

Comment: Indeed relevant. Wondering how I could update z painlessly.

Comment: Replaced Result=U.x+U.y by Result=x+y.

Comment: Can the PIVOT constraint "For I.mykey IN (x,y,z)" be removed ? Could we tell it to create all possible columns ?

Comment: @LudovicAubert you will have to do a dynamic pivot then (with dynamic SQL). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query

Comment: For a complete example of PIVOT/UNPIVOT https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/pivot-and-unpivot-table-in-sql-server

Comment: PIVOT/UNPIVOT can be used to achieve the transformation in both ways.

Answer (score 0):

Turn the 3 rows into a single 3 column row using a common table expression and update it to run the expression. So the proposed solution is an updatable cte.

```
WITH myvalues(x,y,z) AS (
    SELECT x.myvalue, y.myvalue, z.myvalue 
    FROM #key_values AS x
    JOIN #key_values AS y ON y.mykey='y' AND x.mykey='x'
    JOIN #key_values AS z ON z.mykey='z'
)
UPDATE myvalues SET z=x+y;

SELECT myvalue FROM #key_values WHERE mykey='z';
```

[image]